# Append textbox at certain string length

Tags: javascript, html, string, input

I have an Access form which inserts an input field after the previous textbox reaches 8 digits.

[This is how it looks before the user types something with 8 digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acLxg.png)

[When the textbox reaches the string limiter, it creates another input with the same properties and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjnI5.png)

How may I create the same item with JavaScript?

When the textbox get's it's full length limit, I need to append another input and make JavaScript press "tab" to skip to the next element

This is what I've been trying so far.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="opNum_1"  onInput="checkLength(8,this)" onfocus="add_numOp(code);return false;" >
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var counter = 1;
 function checkLength(len,ele){
  var fieldLength = ele.value.length;

  if(fieldLength <= len)
  {

  }
  else
  {
    $(this).keydown();
  }
}

function add_numOp(codigo){


$('#new_Ops_'+codigo+'').append(

        '<div id="opRol_'+codigo+'_'+counter+'" class="quantrolos_'+codigo+'" name="quantrolos_'+codigo+'[]">'+
        '<br/>'+
            '<input type="text" id="opNum_'+codigo+'_'+counter+'" onblur="add_numOp('+myCode+')" style=" margin-left: 28px; "><button type="button"  id="addOp" class="btn btn-rounded btn-default btn-icon" onclick="javascript:remove_op(opRol_'+codigo+'_'+counter+')" ><i  class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>'+
        '</div>'
    );
 counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By targeting our elements and keeping track of their state programmatically,  we can reuse the handler on any number of input elements.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#our-form');
addListener(); // For our initial input event

function addListener() {
  getLastChild().addEventListener('keypress', handler);
}

const appendNewField = () => {
  const newField = form.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
  newField.setAttribute('maxlength', '8');
  return newField;
}

function getLastChild() {
  return form.children[form.children.length - 1];
}

function handler(e) {
  // Ignore tab, backspace, etc https://regex101.com/r/gOSyKu/1
  if (e.target.value.length >= 7 && e.key.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]$/)) {
    // If we are also the last child, append a new sibling
    if (e.target === getLastChild()) {
      const newInput = appendNewField();
      addListener();
    }
    getLastChild().focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="our-form">
  <input type="text" maxlength="8">
</form>
```

Comment: May I use the same item, but with an "div" instead of a form?

Comment: Sure. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element for information about the object returned by document.querySelector

Answer (score -1):

from what i can understand, i simply coded the solution using a global count variable for better accessing of inputs and call focus() for the tab functionality.

```
var count=2;
function checkLength(e){
  if(e.value.length>=8){
    $('#'+e.closest("div").id).append("<input type='text' id='opNum_"+count+"' onInput='checkLength(this)' maxlength='8'>");
    $('#opNum_'+count).focus();
    count++;
  }
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/todadivivu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: can someone suggest why my answer is downvoted , am i somewhere wrong ?